# How to use "IN" and "AND" in sql

Tags: sql, activerecord

i could not use IN and "AND" query in sql

```
SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE ( property_id in(1,2,3) and (admin_approve=0) )
```

Please give a soluction

Comment: Why not start from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp?PHPSESSID=300ae3404d5fa2612f238abeebb8869c).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ is also your friend. Allows people to see some data

Comment: what error do you get? AFAIK know the query is syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the [Grave Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) around the table name in your sql statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   list 
WHERE  ( property_id IN( 1, 2, 3 ) 
         AND ( admin_approve = 0 ) )
```